# Hitting an API Gatway directly without using Ajax - How to structure JSON

Tags: json, ajax, aws-api-gateway

I have in the past only used ajax to make api called. There is a need now for a customer to figure out for them now how hit an AWS Api Gateway programatically. I have been searching for what I need to send to the invoke url, but I cannot find the answer to provide. I'm used to Ajax handling all this in the background.

If I have JSON like this that I want to submit to the Api Gateway:

```
{
"some-key":"some-value",
"some-other-key":"some-other-value",
"some-object":{
  "some-object-key":"some-object-value"
 }
}
```

Is there a way to submit that directly..or do I have to submit it using something like this? Converted to a url string? This is a POST request not a GET request.

https://my-api.com/stage/post/%7B%0A%22some-key%22%3A%22some-value%22%2C%0A%22some-other-key%22%3A%22some-other-value%22%2C%0A%22some-object%22%3A%7B%0A%20%20%22some-object-key%22%3A%22some-object-value%22%0A%20%7D%0A%7D

Essentially: What is the best method for submitting to this api gateway programmatically and submitting JSON and an API KEY. How should it be structured?

Comment: Did you check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-javascript.html ?

Comment: Hey Mohamed. I actually missed that particular page you posted. So, thanks for that. It seems that the easiest way for them to invoke the api gateway is to encourage them to use the AWS SDK itself. I wasn't sure if the could just post directly to the invoke URL.

Comment: Then, mark my answer as solution to close the question, and all the best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this from AWS documentation 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-javascript.html